# High Sierra Xcode: which tools come with Command Line Tools installer?

Tags: install, xcode, software-update

Is this an accurate list? Is there official Apple Documentation detailing which commands get installed?

The [Command Line Tools (macOS 10.13) for Xcode 9.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg) installer was recently made available from Apple:

> This package enables UNIX-style development via Terminal by installing command line developer tools, as well as macOS SDK frameworks and headers. Many useful tools are included, such as the Apple LLVM compiler, linker, and Make. If you use Xcode, these tools are also embedded within the Xcode IDE.

I have macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 and Xcode 9.3 (9E145). From what I gather, these command line tools now are updated with the Xcode IDE installation per the Software Update tool automagic?

FWIW, the [Additional Tools for Xcode 9.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9.3/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg) are also available.

Per [this 2014 osxdaily.com article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/), the binaries are installed for the following commands:

```
ar
as
asa
bison
BuildStrings
c++
c89
c99
cc
clang
clang++
cmpdylib
codesign_allocate
CpMac
cpp
ctags
ctf_insert
DeRez
dsymutil
dwarfdump
dyldinfo
flex
flex++
g++
gatherheaderdoc
gcc
gcov
GetFileInfo
git
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack
gm4
gnumake
gperf
hdxml2manxml
headerdoc2html
indent
install_name_tool
ld
lex
libtool
lipo
lldb
lorder
m4
make
MergePef
mig
mkdep
MvMac
nasm
ndisasm
nm
nmedit
otool
pagestuff
projectInfo
ranlib
rebase
redo_prebinding
ResMerger
resolveLinks
Rez
RezDet
RezWack
rpcgen
segedit
SetFile
size
SplitForks
strings
strip
svn
svnadmin
svndumpfilter
svnlook
svnrdump
svnserve
svnsync
svnversion
unifdef
unifdefall
UnRezWack
unwinddump
what
xml2man
yacc
```

Are they updated as well? Is this an accurate list? Is there official Apple Documentation detailing which commands get installed?